# Prevent URL access to files on website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, content-management-system

I am creating a website with my own CMS. My problem is that I can access certain files via a URL in the browser.

I have tried to block it via `.htaccess` but when I do that, it also stops my functions from working, because they are blocked.

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

Comment: *"I have tryed to block it via .htaccess but when i do that it also stops my functions from working, **because they are blocked**."* You say you want to block access to these files but then complain that they are blocked?

Comment: He wants to avoid people from reaching it directly, but the server should be allowed to access them.

Comment: But when you load a page, and view an embeded image or click on a link on a page, **it is still you that is loading those files**, the server isn't loading anything. If you want to prevent access to those files from being linked elsewhere, then you need to check against the referer, which can be spoofed, so there's no guarantee that you're blocking everything.

Answer (score 0):

Add line at the end of  .htaccess

```
      Options All -Indexes
```

or Use

```
<FilesMatch "*\.(css|js|png)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: This only disables the directory listing, not blocking files from access.

Comment: Use <FilesMatch "*\.(css|js|png)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

Answer (score 0):

Are your functions in a  server side script or a client side script?

If they're server side, you can block HTTP access to the files by putting them in a directory that doesn't need to be accessed through HTTP and then putting a `deny from all` directive in that directory's `htaccess` file.

If they're client side, then you can't block access to them and still have the scripts work. The browser is executing the script, and it needs to access those files. You can do hacky things like refusing to serve the file unless a certain referrer URL is present, but I advise against doing that because it can cause problems with usability, caching, and search engines.

Comment: I didn't initially see that this question was tagged as PHP, so the server side part is what applies. I'll leave the client side part because it's still important to recognize that distinction.